# WPF - Binding and Command on two different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

it goes like this.. I have two viewModels under one same XAML file.

**ViewModel(1)** - Contains a button that has a command that will fire a function inside that view model.

**ViewModel(2)** - Contains a property that are binded to the XAML

**Question**: Is it possible for me to update that particular *property* in **ViewModel(2)** using the *command* in **ViewModel(1)**? If yes, can I have a brief guideline on how to approach it?

The requirement sets me not to make any changes like shifting the *property* to be in the same viewModel as the *command*.

Thank you in advance for any help guys :)

Comment: Cant you simply reference ViewModel(2) from your ViewModel(1) and then when command is invoke, change the property?

Comment: In viewmodel 1 you can store an action which updates the property in viewmodel 2. In viewmodel 1 you cann invoke the action and viewmodel 2 is changed.

Comment: @3615 Hi there, I've just tried it. It works as expected. However, I have no idea why the ppl at my place are trying not to have one viewModel instance inside another viewModel

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Hi there, can you elaborate a lil bit further on this? Is it using Action / Events kind of thing? Im sorry. Reli new to this platform haha..

Comment: If they have reasons not to reference them directly, you can use a Mediator for that. It is simply a Class (often Singleton) to which the diffrenent ViewModels Register, Deregister and Send Messages. (Something like a more indirect way of EventHandling)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a Messenger.
Here is a good article about Messenger in mvvm architecture.
A little bit old, but it could help you imo : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Here is an example, for you. For instance, I use MVVM Light from Galasoft, to be the most straightforward as possible :) http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

First of all, I recommand you to create an Entity related to your message you want to broadcast :
I have added a simple string property, but obviously you can add whatever you want :)

```
public class Vm1toVm2Message
{
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your VM1 you create your message and broadcast it :

```
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand _refreshCommand;
    public RelayCommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _refreshCommand ?? (_refreshCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                // You button command code
                // -------------------

                // Send a message
                Messenger.Default.Send<Vm1toVm2Message>( new Vm1toVm2Message { Message = "Update from VM1" });
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in your VM2, you wait for an incoming message :)

```
public class ViewModel2 : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel2()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<Vm1toVm2Message>(this, HandleVm1toVm2Message);
    }

    private void HandleVm1toVm2Message(Vm1toVm2Message msg)
    {
        // Do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this but it should be a comment, not an answer. Unless you can elaborate and provide and example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
public class FirstViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public delegate void PropertyChangedHandler(object obj);
    public static event PropertyChangedHandler MyPropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        //Example: here I fire the function in the second ViewModel with parameter
        var obj = new { Name = "Jhon" };
        MyPropertyChanged(obj);
    }
}
```

Second ViewModel

```
public class SecondViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SecondViewModel()
    {
        FirstViewModel.MyPropertyChanged += OnMyPropertyChanged;
    }

    public void OnMyPropertyChanged(object obj)
    {
        //...
    }

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In viewmodel 1 you can store an action which updates the property in viewmodel 2. In viewmodel 1 you cann invoke the action and viewmodel 2 is changed.

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void main()
    {
        var vm1 = new ViewModel1();
        var vm2 = new ViewModel2();

        vm1.ChangeValueAction = new Action(() => { vm2.SomeProperty = String.Empty; });
    }
}

public class ViewModel1
{
    public Action ChangeValueAction { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ChangeValueAction.Invoke();
    }
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```